# Laravel logout after page refresh another Laravel project

Tags: laravel-5

When I logged in a Laravel-5 project after logged in when I open another Laravel-5 project in another tab in the same browser, when I refresh the logged in project it redirect to login page.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand

Comment: When i login in admin panel of a laravel project . and then i open another project in another tab.when i again refresh logged in admin panel then it is redirect to login page

Comment: You need to give more information on this issue, there is just too much that could be wrong. how does the routing look like? do you have a redirect somewhere in a controller by mistake? This issue is usually caused by bad placement of routes but i cannot say until some code is posted please.

Answer (score 1):

Go to config folder then in session.php file, change the following

'cookie' => 'laravel_session',

```
TO
```

'cookie' => 'myapp_session',